# Array instead of Array Element

Tags: php, arrays, json, minecraft

I'm trying to turn Minecraft names into UUIDs, which can be converted into a "name history". I have the name->UUID part down pat, but the name history is getting an error.

Running this code, the $uuid variable contains an array of all the UUIDs I'm trying to convert into a name history - I then try to run all of them through the API, and depending on how many past names the user has, add » icons to signify a change. Unfortunately, with test data of something like this:

```
Foo
Bar (changed to Baz)
```

it outputs

```
Array | Array » Array |
```

, not the

```
Foo | Bar » Baz |
```

it's supposed to. I know I'm probably getting the array as an object, but I don't know where I would be doing that or how to get the element instead.

(and here's the code)

```
$uuid_real = json_decode($uuid, TRUE);
foreach($uuid_real as $uuid_totest){

$toadd = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/' . $uuid_totest['id'] . '/names'), TRUE);
if(count($toadd)==1){
    $results .= $toadd['0'] . " | ";
}elseif(count($toadd)==2){
    $results .= $toadd['0'] . " » " . $toadd['1'] . " | ";
}elseif(count($toadd)==3){
    $results .= $toadd['0'] . " » " . $toadd['1'] . " » " . $toadd['2'] . " | ";
}
```

Here is var_dump for $toadd with some currently online users:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "lottie1664"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "wingmanfoutz"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "bigfoot2991"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "mrstampycat05"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "MEHLAWLARZ"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "metboy2002"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "SILVERMAN2"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "salesman200"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Quartzic"
    ["changedToAt"]=>
    int(1423055736000)
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "MercenaryCrow"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "fishmeal"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `$toadd[0]` `$toadd[1]` and `$toadd[2]` are arrays not strings, please provide here var_dump($toadd) and we can help you

EDIT:

So as you can see there is no string under `$toadd[x]` but an array looking like this :

```
 array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "lottie1664"
  }
```

so modify your code and use :

```
$toadd[0]['name']
$toadd[1]['name']
$toadd[2]['name']
```